# MonoTouch: "file too small for architecture i386" -- FlurryAnalytics.dll

Tags: xamarin.ios

I added the `FlurryAnalytics.dll` from the `mono-monotouch-bindings` project in GitHub. But when I compile I get this compiler error that is a big baffling.

```
/var/folders/15/47k2732n643g9dcrz5sncc6c0000gn/T/tmp30974428.tmp/
libFlurryAnalytics.a, file too small for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current library was incorrectly built. I will push the correct version tonight.

In the meantime, add libFlurryAnalytics.a back to the directory and run the makefile using the `make` command. You can find libFlurryAnalytics.a from the SDK Download Provided by Flurry.